# SQLite - Sort and get the number in the list

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, list, sqlite

```
sql.all(`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC`).then()
```

How can I sort the list and get the current number on the list?
Example:

```
LIST:
USERID | POINTS
1 | 20
2 | 100
3 | 67

VAR MYID = 1

Output: your the number 3 in the list
```

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`.  But use a parameter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want `3` as a result, you can do:

```
select 1 + count(*) pos
from mytable t
where points > (select points from mytable t1 where userid = :myid)
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions:

```
select pos
from (select t.*, rank() over(order by points) pos from mytable) t
where userid = :myid
```